# Is it possible to change a trustedCertEntry key to a privateKeyEntry afterwards?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, ssl-certificate

I´m trying to release a new version to an app I´m fixing to play store. 
The guys that used to publish it and work on it are no longer working at our company so it´s up to me to publish a new version.

The problem is that the key from our keystore that they used is trustedCertEntry and not PrivateKeyEntry as it has to be (I´m pretty sure?). Now I just get the error: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> Failed to read key advaniamobile-alias from store "my keystore path": trusted certificate entries are not password-protected.

Is there any way I can use this key so I don´t have to create a new application on play store? Is it possible to change the key afterwards?

I´m not really experienced with these keys so a detailed answer would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!